# Pandas add column with the total after groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I did a `groupby` and `sum` on my df, and now it looks like this:

```
Count   Count   Count   Count
God's Mountain          
LANG     English     French      Spanish 
SCP Foundation  0,0,0   
The Rules of Survival   7.0 2.0 1.0
Title       0,0,0
```

Formatted:

```
{('Count', ' English '): {'The Rules of Survival': 7.0, "God's Mountain": nan, 'SCP Foundation': nan, 'The Raven': 164.0, 'Gli arancini di Montalbano': 2.0}, ('Count', ' French '): {'The Rules of Survival': 2.0, "God's Mountain": nan, 'SCP Foundation': nan, 'The Raven': 14.0, 'Gli arancini di Montalbano': 3.0}, ('Count', ' Spanish '): {'The Rules of Survival': 1.0, "God's Mountain": nan, 'SCP Foundation': nan, 'The Raven': 15.0, 'Gli arancini di Montalbano': 2.0}, ('Count', 'Undetected'): {'The Rules of Survival': 6.0, "God's Mountain": 3.0, 'SCP Foundation': 2.0, 'The Raven': 807.0, 'Gli arancini di Montalbano': 7.0} }
```

I would like to add a Total column, so that I would get

```
LANG     English     French      Spanish, Total
SCP Foundation  0,0,0, 0    
The Rules of Survival   7.0 2.0 1.0, 10.0
Title       0,0,0, 0
```

This is the whole code:

```
d2 = d2.groupby(['Title', 'LANG'], sort=False).sum().unstack()
d2.loc['Column_Total'] = d2.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=0)
print(d2['Column_Total'])
```

When I print it, it looks the same because the names of the column are a bit skewed I think, or I don't have other explanations

Comment: Please reformat your dataframe.

Comment: how do I do it?

Comment: The best you can do is to provide a sample of your dataframe before groupby. `print(d2.head().to_dict())` for example.

Comment: done + see my edit, but the df has A LOT of columns

Comment: You want the sum without `Undetected` column I guess?

Answer (score 0):

Your dataframe looks weird but I guess you want an additional Column with the total?
So starting from:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {('Count', ' English '): {'The Rules of Survival': 7.0, "God's Mountain": np.nan, 'SCP Foundation': np.nan, 'The Raven': 164.0, 'Gli arancini di Montalbano': 2.0}, ('Count', ' French '): {'The Rules of Survival': 2.0, "God's Mountain": np.nan, 'SCP Foundation': np.nan, 'The Raven': 14.0, 'Gli arancini di Montalbano': 3.0}, ('Count', ' Spanish '): {'The Rules of Survival': 1.0, "God's Mountain": np.nan, 'SCP Foundation': np.nan, 'The Raven': 15.0, 'Gli arancini di Montalbano': 2.0}, ('Count', 'Undetected'): {'The Rules of Survival': 6.0, "God's Mountain": 3.0, 'SCP Foundation': 2.0, 'The Raven': 807.0, 'Gli arancini di Montalbano': 7.0} }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1
```

[image]

**The Solution** might be simply do it like this :

```
df1['total']=df1.sum(axis=1)
df1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to add a new column with total values.
So this might help you:

```
d2['','Column_Total'] = d2.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=1)
```

Or if you do not use multiindex at columns just

```
d2['Column_Total']= d2.sum(axis=1)
```